# How do you use setRamImage in panda3d?

Tags: python, panda3d

Edit:
A minimal failing test case is now on github here:
https://github.com/shadowmint/Panda-setRamImage-problem

--

I have a C library that passes an unsigned char * pointer back to python with RGB pixel data in it.

The python api to do this is:

```
# unsigned char *ar_get_rgb(void *handle);
libar.ar_get_rgb.argtypes = [ c_void_p ]
libar.ar_get_rgb.restype = POINTER(c_char)
```

In panda3d I'm trying to render this data as a texture. There's a blog post here about how to that:
http://www.panda3d.org/blog/?p=96

However, I found that doing this has some pretty serious limitations, which I've discussed here: http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13183, and as I result I'm now trying to use the setRamImage() api to set texture memory.

There seems like there must be a way to do this, but the only way I'm able to at the moment is using a pixel-by-pixel set call on the texture, as follows:

```
  def updateTextureTask(self, t):
    expectedSize = self.getExpectedRamImageSize()
    print("Expected length: " + str(expectedSize))
    (rgb, depth) = self.__vision.next()
    p = PTAUchar.emptyArray(expectedSize)
    for i in range(0, self.__vision.width * self.__vision.height * 3):
      p.setElement(i, ord(rgb[i]))
    print("PTAU length: " + str(p.size()))
    self.setRamImage(CPTAUchar(p))
    return Task.cont
```

This works...but it runs at a stunning 1 frame every 2 seconds.

If I call p.setData(rgb) to set the data of the PTAUchar (hint: http://www.panda3d.org/dox/python/html/classpanda3d_1_1core_1_1PTAUchar.html) I get:

```
Expected length: 921600
RGB buffer size: 921600 <-- C debugging data
PTAU length: 4
Assertion failed: compression != CM_off || image.size() == do_get_expected_ram_image_size() at line 833 of panda/src/gobj/texture.cxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I'm puzzled as to where this '4' length comes from, because of a dump of the first 20 odd values in the RGB array is like:

```
0: 163, 1: 151, 2: 162, 3: 85, 4: 83, 5: 190, 6: 241, 7: 252, 8: 249, 9: 121, 10: 107, 11: 82, 12: 20, 13: 19, 14: 233, 15: 226, 16: 45, 17: 81, 18: 142, 19: 31
PTAU length: 4
```

There must be a way to convert my unsigned char * array into something that can feed into PTAUchar.setData or PTAUchar.setSubdata, but I can't figure it out.

help!

Comment: If you use a recent development build of Panda, you should be able to pass any object exposing the Python buffer protocol to the PTAUchar constructor, which would be far more efficient than copying via a string.  See also the latest post on the Panda3D blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for the `setData` function is:

```
PTAUchar.setData(string data)
```

You're not passing a string. You're passing a pointer to a string. I think what you want to do is have your C library pass a python byte string back to your python code, and then pass that to `setData`.

PS: Coming to #panda3d on freenode is a great place to get real-time help.

Comment: Helpful, but this is really generic advice. Can you be more specific? A c_char_p type makes c return a python string, but it is NULL terminated, which means you cannot pass, for example, BLACK PIXELS (or any pixel with a 0 component), back, making the API completely useless.

Comment: A python string can definitely have a 0 byte in it. Maybe you want PyString_FromStringAndSize?

Comment: The missing step was converting the POINTER(c_char) into a string using rgb = rgb[:expectedSize] // PTAUchar.setData(rgb).